# Running Node.js server on centos on vagrant

Tags: node.js, centos, vagrant

I'd like to run Node.js server in virtual machine.

I executed `vagrant up` and `node Server.js`.
Then I accessed to `http://192.168.33.10:1337/` from host machine browser.
But, the browser outputs `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.
How do I fix it?

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
end
```

Server.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "192.168.33.10");

console.log('server running');
```

Comment: you should not need to indicate the IP on the server (as it is its own IP) remove this part - also add a `console.log(request.url);` in the createServer method to make sure request are being addressed correctly and the server prints out the message

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure the box has binded to the right address as @frederic said.
2. Make sure its not the firewall: sudo service iptables stop
3. Make sure your host (your computer) can access the vagrant VM.
   3a. If you bridged, use the internal IP of the VM
   3b. If you port-forwarded into the VM ( config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080 ), use http://localhost:8080 from your host (your computer).